# ScrollView - colorEdgeEffect in API 10

Tags: android, api, scrollview, glow, overscroll

I'd like to remove the blue glow in ScrollView and keep overscrolling so overScrollMode="never" is not an option. Is there any way to do it on API 10? Or at least not higher than 14.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the fading edge of the scrollview and as far my knowledge there is a property in the view i.e setScrollbarFadingEnabled(boolean) to enable or disable the fading edge.

You can give it a try as it is from API level 5.

Comment: are you trying it on above ICS device or below because this will be ignored after ICS

Comment: well I want to make an app for 10+ so yes

Comment: I've found a way, it can be done by creating your own scrollview by extending it and overriding some class methods.